# Clone and link child using AsNoTracking in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have following 3 Entity:
`Order`   `*-1`   `People`   `*-*`    `Tag`

I need to deep CLONE people and its orders and LINK its tag(tag are shared to all people and should not be Cloned)

I am using following Query to clone a people

`var newPeople = dbcontext.Include(s => s.Orders).AsNoTracking().Include(s => s.Tags).Single(s => s.ID == id)
dbcontext.Peoples.Add(newPeople);`

the orders was cloned but entity framework try to clone to Tags too, which cause duplicate Tag insert, I just need to clone the relation between tag-people rather than clone a new tag.

Is there any way link instead of clone many to many children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A deep clone is a clone of an object that also clones that are dependent on it... You want a partially deep clone, since you only want to clone the Orders, and not the Tag object(s).
To do that, you first have to load your object, and include the parts of it you want cloned, followed by AsNoTracking, so that they aren't tracked as already existing entities:

```
var newPeople = dbcontext.Include(s => s.Orders).AsNoTracking().Single(s => s.ID == id)
```

Afterwards, you add the new object to the table of objects of that type

```
dbcontext.Peoples.Add(newPeople);
dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

but before returning, you might want to save the Id of the newly cloned item, which is done with this line, **after** the SaveChanges one

```
var cloneId = newPeople.Id
```

cloneId now has the Id of the new item, so if you then want the full clone in memory, you do another load from the database, like this:

```
var fullNewPeopleClone = dbcontext.Include(s => s.Orders).Include(s => s.Tags).Single(s => s.ID == cloneId)
```

Comment: No, It still try cloning new Tags. cause duplicate key error.

Comment: @CharlesChou allright, check the edited answer, that's what you need to do in order to obtain partially deep clones.

Comment: without .Include(s => s.Tags), Neither new "Tags" nor it relations are cloned. the new people have no tags

Comment: I am thinking of using DTO(Data Transfer Object)

Comment: Check edited answer again, this time I was more detailed.